# YUI3 autocomplete call for focus event

Tags: autocomplete, focus, yui3

I'm trying to call focus() on a YUI3 autocomplete control, but nothing happens.

The code is:

```
var ac = new Y.AutoComplete({ inputNode: '#ac-input' });
ac.focus(); //doesn't do anything
ac.fire('focus'); //neither this
ac.simulate("focus"); //no success either, yes I did include 'node-event-simulate'
ac.invoke("focus"); //no success either
```

replaced 'focus' with 'click' but nothing.

Tried using focusmanager, but no success yet.

How do I focus the query field of the autocomplete?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think ac is not a the node you think it is.

Try to call the focus method on the input node.

```
var inputNode = Y.one('#ac-input'),
    ac = new Y.AutoComplete({ inputNode: inputNode });

inputNode.focus();
```

Comment: Thanks, @ludo, I did that with no success, nothing happenes when focus(). However, I tried to capture focus event of the autocomplete's textbox element, something like **Y.on('focus', function(){ alert(...);})** and it captured the event! That means the event fired and got captured by the relevant element, but nothing happens on screen (I expect to see what I type in the textbox). Any idea?

Comment: What element is '#ac-input' node? Is it an input?
http://jsbin.com/epudag/1/edit works for me.